# How can I get 'percent difference' like in an Excel PivotTable?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on Pandas and would like to mimic the result as the PivotTable in Excel 2013. I use pd.pandas to get the result with sum of values, but I cannot figure out how to get the '% Diff', for example, how can I get the percent value comparing data of Jan. with Feb.

Like this in Excel:

[image: sample]
<sub>(source: [pivot-table.com](http://www.pivot-table.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/percentdifference08.png))</sub>

Comment: I think, this is what you want: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html

Comment: thanks! @Maecky. I will try.